# column new_value and display type and value of a variable

Tags: sql, oracle, debugging

```
column dcol new_value mydate noprint
select to_char(sysdate - case
                    when to_char(sysdate, 
'hh24:mi:ss') between '17:00:00' and '23:59:59' then 0
                    when to_char(sysdate, 
'hh24:mi:ss') between '00:00:00' and '17:00:00' then 1
                end,'YYYYMMDD') dcol
from dual;

set feedback off

spool "C:\test\test_&mydate..csv";

select /*csv*/ * from REPORTS.TEST;

spool off;
```

Hi,

I have the above SQL query that was written by someone else. I'm trying to understand and follow it.
I have the following questions - wonder if someone could help me with them?

1) There are 2 instances of 'dcol' in the query:
a) column dcol, then b) select dcol from dual. Is 'dcol' a column name from dual table? It seems that if I replace 'dcol' with 'random_col' - 
the query still work the same

2) "C:\test\test_&mydate..csv"; why is there a double '.' as opposed to single '.' right before 'csv'?

3) How do I debug the SQL query in Oracle SQL Developer? For example, in the following:

```
select to_char(sysdate - case
                    when to_char(sysdate, 
'hh24:mi:ss') between '17:00:00' and '23:59:59' then 0
                    when to_char(sysdate, 
'hh24:mi:ss') between '00:00:00' and '17:00:00' then 1
                end,'YYYYMMDD') dcol
from dual;
```

I want to find out: a) what is the value of sysdate?, b) which case, select falls into?

4) If at the end of the SQL query, I add: Define mydate; I would get the following output:

DEFINE MYDATE          = "20181126" (VARCHAR2)

Is there other ways to display what the variable mydate is and its type?

Answer (score 1):

1) dcol is the column_name for the output of the dual query

```
select to_char(sysdate - case
                    when to_char(sysdate, 
'hh24:mi:ss') between '17:00:00' and '23:59:59' then 0
                    when to_char(sysdate, 
'hh24:mi:ss') between '00:00:00' and '17:00:00' then 1
                end,'YYYYMMDD') dcol
from dual;


output.....
+----------+
|   dcol   |
+----------+
| 20181126 |
+----------+
```

The first line of your code says 
column dcol new_value mydate noprint.

This means to store the value of dcol and put that into the "sql plus/sqldeveloper" variable mydate.

NB This is a sqlplus command which is understood by the sqlplus program/sqldeveloper (Its not a standard PL/SQL) command.

```
set feedback off 
means suppress the query status such as
42 rows returned..
```

2) "C:\test\test_&mydate..csv"; why is there a double '.' as opposed to single '.' right before 'csv'?.

You would need a .. to escape the "." in sqlplus/sqldeveloper program.

Spool command is a sqlplus thing. here you notice that you are creating a "csv" file with the file name as that returned from the 1) output which is present in the variable &mydate

```
select /*csv*/ * from REPORTS.TEST;
```

This is a syntax in sqldeveloper, which will generate csv file as the output.
Check this link to see how easy it is to generate csv

https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/05/formatting-query-results-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer/

spool off means create the file in C:\test\test_20181126.csv

3) Just run the query as is.

4) Just give this a try select &mydate from dual;

Comment: Did i answer your query